# Objects don't move , How to make bullets move

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make an enemy who will shoot at the player. I turn the pool during its appearance and try to start it, but for some reason it does not move

I have two scripts for the bullet script, and a script for the enemy who shoots bullets

At first I tried to make a bullet move with the help of `AddForce(transform.up * Speed);`
[image]

For bullet

```
public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject bullet;

    void Start()
    {
        bullet.transform.Translate(bullet.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

for enemy

```
public class TurelScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Player;
    public Transform Turell;
    public GameObject PrefabOfbullet;
    public Transform BUlletPosition;

    public float Rotation;

    void Start()
    {
        var turnOfBullet = Quaternion.Lerp(BUlletPosition.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, Player.position - BUlletPosition.position), Time.deltaTime * 40f);
        var rigidbodyBullet = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


        StartCoroutine(BulletSpawn());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var turn = Quaternion.Lerp(Turell.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, Player.position - Turell.position), Time.deltaTime * 4f);
        var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


        rigidbody.MoveRotation(turn.eulerAngles.z);
    }


    IEnumerator BulletSpawn()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Instantiate(PrefabOfbullet, BUlletPosition.position, Turell.rotation);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the bullet seems to be a `Rigidbody2D` you shouldn't use `Transform.Translate` **at all** but only change it though the `Rigidbody2D` component and in `FixedUpdate` for not breaking Physics. (See [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html))

Then for a bullet you almost never want to use [`AddForce`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html) which would require to know the bullets' mass and calculate the required force accordingly.

You rathet instantly change its [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) so rather do something like

```
// Having the correct type allows you only to reference
// Object that actually have this type
// And second you don't need `GetComponent` on runtime
public Rigidbody2D PrefabOfBullet;

// Set the speed you want in Unity Units / second
public float BulletSpeed = 1f;

...

var bullet = Instantiate (PrefabOfBullet, Bullet position.position, Turell.rotation);
bullet.velocity = bullet.transform.up * BulletSpeed;

...
```